# What's meaning of "pictures of mountains looking up"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> It`s always snowy in the Himalayas. Parts of the Asian mountain chain
>   never see a day without it.  It's easy to find pictures of these
>   majestic mountains looking up. http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1503/10/sn.01.html

What's meaning of "pictures of mountains looking up"?

Does it mean the picture of mountains that a person took while looking up the mountains?

Comment: It does not mean that a person was looking up the mountains when taking pictures of it. "Picture" is used to mean the high standing mountain as an observable object. Also used to create a mental picture of the tall majestic mountain. It is used as a verb which means "to Imagine; conceive of; see in one's mind."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many meanings that *up* has as an adjective is in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/up):

> Facing upwards; facing toward the top.

Put the notebook face up on the table. Take a break and put your feet up.

No mountain is standing facing down. *Looking up* just means ""*facing toward the sky*""